# Programmatically get the first row from a GridView after changing pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, page-index-changed

Can anyone tell me how I would get the data from a row in a DataGrid after a page changes.  I am currently trying the following:

```
protected void MissionariesGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string missionaryID = MissionariesGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
    TestLabel.Text = missionaryID;
}
```

The problem is, I do not get the value for the first row in the new page. I am getting the value for the first row in the old page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for that should be in the RowCreated or RowDataBound event handler... The PageIndexChanged happens too soon I think.

Comment: Does not work in either one of these events.  I get an error for "Index out of Range".

Comment: Yes sorry left out a detail: in the index changed handler, you should explicitly rebind the grid view. So set MissionariesGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex then call DataBind(). After that your logic in RowCreated should work

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with your help.  I was still getting the "Index out of range" error when the page was loading.  I had to check that I had at least one row in the RowCreated event before executing the code. I appreciate your help on this.